# how to split a for loop in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want have a simple model for images. there is a option to upload unlimited images. but I want don't want them to be shown under each other. for instance just show the first 5 images then some text and then again another 5.
right now my code is like this:

```
{% for img in images %}
 <img src="{{ img.images.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

I want the Structure to be like this:

- for loop for img0 to 5,
- then everything elese,
- then another for loop for img6 to 10,

Thanks for the solutions and apologies for my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for img in images|slice:":5" %}
    <img src="{{ img.images.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
{% endfor %}

…

{% for img in images|slice:"5:10" %}
    <img src="{{ img.images.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```